# Import library into Angular2/WebPack project without NPM

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, yfiles

I'm completely new to Angular2 and WebPack and am struggling with something probably very simple.

We're trying to incorporate [yFiles for HTML](https://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles-for-html) into an Agular2/WebPack project.  I've found and imported the types file on NPM at `@types/yfiles`.  The rest of the library is only available from the vendor, not on NPM.  This compiles correctly, but when I debug the project, the console reports the error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: yfiles is not defined
>   Error: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: yfiles is not defined

It's not the HomeComponent so much as the DiagramComponent it references that's having the problem.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'fs-diagram',
  templateUrl: './diagram.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./diagram.component.scss']
})
export class DiagramComponent implements OnInit {
  private canvas: yfiles.view.CanvasComponent;

  constructor() {
    this.canvas = new yfiles.view.CanvasComponent();
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

The folder structure looks like this:

```
> root
  > .vscode
  > node_modules
  ▼ src
    > app
    ▼ lib
      ▼ yfiles
        > impl
          *.js
        yfiles.css
    > public
    > style
      main.ts
      polyfill.ts
      vendor.ts
    npm-shrinkwrap.json
    package.json
    protractor.conf.js
    tsconfig.json
    tslint.json
    typedoc.json
    webpack.config.js
```

I get the feeling that the even though the `@types/yfiles/index.d.ts` file is present, it's looking for the `*.js` files at run time.  Is that the problem, and if so, how do I import them into the project?

Comment: did you try importing it? import { Co... etc cause nowhere do I see you referencing yfiles in your code. so how would your code know where to pick it up (npm does this automatically for you)

Comment: did you also try to contact the vendor and/or read the documentation they have?

Comment: Try adding just adding
`import ../lib/yfiles` since it appears to be a global.

Comment: You definitely have to import the yFiles modules as well. The TypeScript definition file only exists to supply types to the TypeScript compiler, it doesn't contain any actual *implementation*. I don't really know enough about Angular and TS to really answer how to import modules, but we have an Angular 2 demo in `demos/toolkit/angular2`. Maybe you'll look at that one first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have webpack include the yFiles modules in the bundle, they will indeed have to be imported in your Typescript file:

```
import yfiles = require("yfiles/view");
```

To make this work, webpack also needs to be told where the modules can be found - with webpack 2.x, this can be specified using the `resolve.modules` config in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "dist/bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    modules: ["./lib"] // the lib folder containing the yFiles modules
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks!  That pointed my to the missing piece.  I had to use `modules: ['./node_modules', './lib']` ultimately.

Comment: Note that with yFiles for HTML 2.1 this has all become a lot easier. There is now a dedicated angular-cli demo in the package that makes use of the native ES6 modules variant of yFiles.